# background-image: url() does not work with link contains a space

Tags: html, css

I have a link with a backround image.

The problèm: `background-image: url()` doesn't work with link contain space. I tried to encode the url but didn't work:

```
<a href="#" style="background-image: url(http://127.0.0.1:8082/server/php/files/1 (2).jpg)"></a>
```

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Spaces are represented as `%20` in HTML, but I recommend simply renaming your file to **not** have a space. As an alternative, wrapping the string inside `url()` in single-quotes should work as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Embed the address with single quotes,

```
 <a href="#" style="background-image: url('http://127.0.0.1:8082/server/php/files/1 (2).jpg')">
```

or, preferably, don't use spaces.

Comment: Thank you for replying i really appreciate, i will change the file renaming process. I will accept your response i 8 minutes